# How can update_all fail without raising an exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, update-all

I have problem with storing data into Postgres using `update_all`.
To explain the problem, we have 2 classes, `Meter` and `Readings`. Every meter has many readings. Meter has attributes `unit`, like energy unit kWh, MWh, ..., and `multiplier`, number that multiplies readings state to get final value.
When user wants to update `Meter` params (`unit`, `multiplier`), we use `Interactors` to firstly update `Readings` states and then save `Meter` itself.
All these operations happen in single transaction, so if one fails, then all fail.
But we came in situation, when meter is saved and readings are not updated or vice versa.
I checked, that when meter does not save correctly, it causes `context.fail!`. `Readings` uses `update_all` without any check of success, but I read, that `update_all` goes directly to the DB and when it fails on constraints, it fails with an exception.

I did not find any way, how to replicate it.

```
// update readings
class Meters::ChangeUnit
   // includes

   def call
      coefficient = 1.0
      coefficient *= unit_change if context.meter.energy_unit_changed?
      coefficient *= multiplier_change if context.meter.multiplier_changed?

      return if coefficient == 1.0

      // this probably fails:
      context.meter.readings.update_all "state = state * #{coefficient}"
   end

   // ...

end

// save meter
class Meters::Save
    include Meters::BaseInteractor

    def call
        context.fail! meter_errors: context.meter.errors unless context.meter.save
    end
end
```

My idea is to use something like this into `Meters::ChangeUnit call`:

```
 // ...
 cnt = context.meter.readings.count
 updated = context.meter.readings.update_all "state = state * #{coefficient}"
 unless cnt == updated
   context.fail! updated_meter_readings: "#{updated}/#{cnt}"
 end
 // ...
```

but I have no idea, how to prove it.

EDIT1:

```
 // usage in cotroller
 context = UpdateMeter.call(meter: @meter, bonds_definition: params[:meters_ids])


 // UpdateMeter
 class UpdateMeter
    include Interactor::Organizer

    organize Meters::Update, ProcessAfterCommitQueue
 end




// Meters::Update
class Meters::Update
  include Interactor::Organizer
  include Interactor::InTransaction

  organize Meters::ValidateActive,
           // ...
           Meters::ChangeUnit,
           // ...
           Meters::Save,
           // ...
end



// Interactor::InTransaction
module Interactor::InTransaction
   extend ActiveSupport::Concern

   included do
      around do |interactor|
         ActiveRecord::Base.transaction { interactor.call }
      end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

(comment can't format, so here it is in an answer)

I don't see a transaction.  Without unwinding your code, I don't understand why this isn't just

```
Meter.transaction do
  context.meter.save
  interactor.call
end
```

Comment: I edited the description.
It uses another interactor to do it all in single transaction.

Comment: I tweaked the answer so that it  seems closer to your code - which I still have trouble parsing.  It seems like you're trying to do too much and not letting rails just do its thing, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was all about threads. We found out, that this problem occurred just several times within last few years. So it was really edge case.

There are two operations. One is mentioned meter params update by user, and the other is automatic import of readings from actual devices (physical meters).
When import starts, it selects the unit and multiplier (action 1), modifies readings and saves them into the DB (action 2). But those 2 actions are not in the same transaction. So if user saved meter between those 2 actions, we would save wrong data, coz of updated unit or multiplier.

We resolved that using `meter.reload` in transaction with `readings.save`. We compare meter before reload and after reload, and if it has changed, we have to recalculate readings.